# Index on 'GROUP BY' with functions

Tags: mysql, index, functions, group-by

I have a log table. It logs visitor data (time of visit, browser, window size ...).

I want to create reports. I use a query like this (MySQL):

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) as raw_views ...
FROM logs
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

The problem is `DATE(timestamp)`. I am using a function on this field, so the index won't work. But the table is huge. Index are very important. But how else can I create hourly, daily, yearly, monthly reports?

I tried to find out how others are doing it. For example Piwik (an open source Google Analytics like script). But I don't really get it.

Comment: `GROUP BY` can only be used if you have an aggregate, of which you have none.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code.

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239/storing-vs-calculating-aggregate-values

Comment: I can't store aggregated values like that. There are MANY reason in my scenario but for example: I want daily, hourly, yearly reports.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support indexes on expressions or functions

Comment: Ok, so how should I proceed?

Comment: You can have hourly, daily, yearly tables where you store the aggregated results. You only need to calculate once for a year. Once you have the 2013 statistics, you don't need to redo them, right?

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to be almost live. Also aggreated results would not be efficient because those logs are not for one user. They are for different user. However I do generate archived reports for reports a user has requested. But they are only valid for 30 minutes.

Comment: How can **cached** (stored in tables) aggregate results not be efficient?

Comment: I am doing this already. I generate them on the fly if user request a report. But I can't just simply only store aggregate values. I have many user and the report is different for every one. In the log table there is a colum `user_id` which stores a id of a user to know to who this entry belongs. Anyway... so there is no "trick" to still use index?

Comment: You changed the query from `DATE(timestamp)` to `HOUR(timestamp)`. In your comments you mention users as well, yet the code has nothing about users. If you want good answers, please edit the question with the queries you have and the table definition. And you really should have done that in the first place, not after 3 days and having 4 people wasting their time answering a question that changes scope.

Comment: @ypercube Yes I am really sorry. But the provided answer did help me too (but not on that specific question). However I did realize the mistake to late and was acutally a little bit confused about the answers. But now I get it! I was wondering if I should leave this question as is (without the edit) because the answers to match the original question and start a new one?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the original query

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) as raw_views ...
FROM logs
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

It appears that you are looking for counts for just today. In that instance, why use `GROUP BY` at all ? You should run

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) as raw_views ...
FROM logs
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE();
```

OK, let's get a little more granular. You said you have reports per `user_id`

Perhaps the query could be adjusted per user

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) as raw_views
FROM logs
WHERE userid = <some number>
AND timestamp >= CURDATE();
```

In that case, you can index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE logs ADD INDEX userid_timestamp_index (user_id,timestamp);
```

If you are getting all the user raw count in one shot, you would query like this

```
SELECT
    user_id,COUNT(*) as raw_views
FROM logs
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY user_id
;
```

In that case, you can index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE logs ADD INDEX timestamp_userid_index (timestamp,user_id);
```

This is all I can suggest with what you have given. Hope this help !!!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an additional column, date, which stores the function date(timestamp) on insertion. This won't make the group by extremely efficient, but it can avoid the temporary table.

The second problem is the range + GROUP BY, which would make an index on (timestamp, date) useless (BTREE limitations). You can create just an index on (date) or better, on (date, timestamp) if you are using 5.6 with Index Condition Pushdown and do:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) as raw_views ...
FROM logs
WHERE date >= CURDATE() and timestamp >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY date
```

Again, this will be better than before, but it will not make the group by radically efficient.

There are several options for that, the most direct is the one that @Remus Rusanu mentioned, calculating aggregates. If you need them "in real time", you can update them on every insert, adding +1 with a trigger, for example, but that will reduce quite significantly your insertion rate. Usually, those are cached for several usages, as @ypercube mentions, and only recalculated every some time.

Maybe you are using the wrong tool: MySQL is not the best tool for analytics/aggregate results. Think of [column-based storages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS)- there are even some propietary implementations as MySQL storage engines.

Comment: Some, such as InfiniDB are Open Source - Infobright is also, but less so. I think that InfiniDB is an interesting project - it's even starting to put sorely needed windowing functions into MySQL. Even better for this sort of work would be PostgreSQL **IF** you can change - or use a second server as a data warehouse.

Comment: Well, I actually used proprietary as in "exclusive/non common/owned" rather than non-free.

Answer (score 1):

First create a Calendar table (a table of dates) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates); then extend it by adding and populating Year, MonthName, DayOfMonth, and Tomorrow columns in that table and add a unique index on it by (Year, MonthName and DayOfMonth), and another unique index on it by the base column (Date) - the Primary Key.

Now you can generate your reports by joining to the Calendar table (assume it is called Calendar) like this:

```
SELECT 
    Year,MonthName,
    count(*) as raw_views
from logs
join Calendar on _data <= Timestamp and TimeStamp < Tomorrow
group by Year,MonthName
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
select sum(N), the_date from (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as N, timestamp, DATE(timestamp) as the_date
    FROM logs
    WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
    group by timestamp
) as A
GROUP BY the_date -- or: GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

Your first problem is MySQL, for many reasons, here because `function(column)` shouldn't preclude the use of an index on `column`.  The above query might engender consultation of the column at the price of two aggregations.